# Interpolation space of mixed Lorentz-Lebesgue spaces

Tags: interpolation-spaces

Is it true that the real interpolation space
$$ (L^{q_0}_{r_0} L^{p_0}, L^{q_1}_{r_1} L^{p_1})_{\theta,q} = L^q L^p_q $$
with
$$ \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1-\theta}{q_0} + \frac{\theta}{q_1}, \text{ and } \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1-\theta}{p_0} + \frac{\theta}{p_1}?$$

#### Definitions and remarks:

- $(X_0,X_1)_{\theta,q}$ denote the real interpolation space
- $L^{q}_r L^p$ denote the space of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that the mapping $t \mapsto \|f(t)\|_p$ is in the Lorentz space $L^q_r$  (the indices are such that $L^q_1 \subset L^q \subset L^q_\infty$).
- For the mixed Lebesgue spaces the complex interpolation holds
  $$ (L^{q_0} L^{p_0}, L^{q_1} L^{p_1})_{[\theta]} = L^q L^p $$
  (Theorem 5.1.2 in Bergh and Lofstrom.)
- Bergh and Lofstrom also mentions that the real interpolation
  $$ (L^{q_0}L^{p_0}, L^{q_1}L^{p_1})_{\theta,q} = L^q L^p_q $$
  in comment 5.8.6 (due to Lions-Peetre), and stating that replacing the $q$ on the left hand side by arbitrary $r$ doesn't give anything reasonable (due to Cwikel).
- It certainly is true that
  $$ (L^{q_0}_{r_0} L^p, L^{q_1}_{r_1} L^p)_{\theta,r} = L^q_r L^p $$
  when $q, \theta, q_0, q_1$ satisfy the usual conditions.